# ¿Cómo hago una comparación si tengo dos clases?

Tags: java

Tengo dos clases y quiero hacer una comprobación de trabajos.

```
public class Trabajos {

    String rubro;
    
    public Local(String rubro) {
        this.rubro = rubro;
        
    }

    public boolean esEsencial() {
        boolean respuesta = true;
        if( rubro == Trabajo Nombre /*o*/ String Nombre)
        Llamar a la otra variable de la otra clase del parámetro y comprobar si son esenciales o no

        }
        return respuesta;
    }
    
}
```

Creo las instancias correspondientes

```
Trabajo Alm = new Trabajo("Alimentacion");
Trabajo Farm = new Trabajo("Farmacia");
```

```
public class Persona {
    
    public Comprobar(String Nombre /*o*/ Trabajo Nombre) {
//Decir el nombre aca y llevarlo a la clase Trabajo. No se si es Trabajo Nombre.
    }
}
```

Luego esta la clase Persona.
Lo que quiero hacer es que en el método de la clase Persona poner como parametro el trabajo mio, y que ese dato llevarlo a la clase Trabajo al metodo esEsencial y se haga una comprobacion con las instancias

Es  decir que el trabajo que tengo comprobar con las instancias si son iguales
Si no son iguales por lo tanto es porque no son esenciales. Es decir que si no es Farmacia por ejemplo mi trabajo no es esencial.

Las instancias estan creadas en el main. Por lo tanto cuando creo una Persona

```
p.comprobar(Peluquero)
```

Como dije peluquero y como no es esencial porque los esenciales son los que cree como instancia. daría un false en metodo esEsencial().

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres realizar. Creo que aclararía mucho que dijeras, en lenguaje natural, cuál es la regla de negocio o situación de la vida real que estás tratando de modelar, sin hablar de clases ni de instancias. Luego, ya ver cómo lo estás implementando y qué es lo que te está fallando.

Comment: Lo que intento es tener un metodo y que sea si puedo ir a comprar o no tal dia. Y tener en cuenta si me Aislo es falso y si el local es esencial. Donde es esencial esta en la otra clase. Y yo le tendria que preguntar a donde quiere ir y comrprobar si es esencial o no realmente

Comment: Onda tengo que comprobar si por ej yo digo Peluqueria es esencial o no ese local. Y me imagino que tendre muchos objetos como Farmacia y Tienda, etc. Y si no esta el objeto Peluqueria es porque no es esencial o si lo llegue a interpretar yo.

Comment: Creo que lo que tratas de hacer es verificar si una persona puede o no salir de su casa dependiendo si el lugar al que quiere ir es o no esencial para tenerlo abierto. ¿Correcto? ¿Qué lenguaje estás usando?

Comment: Hola! Claro. Es java! Donde intento hacer esa comprobacion en la clase Trabajo del metodo esEsencial(); Para que me devuelva un valor boolean. Y ahi en la clase Persona. Solo llamo al metodo pero sin crear instancias para saber si es un false o true. Por que si ves en el grafico dice Local Lugar que en verdad es Trabajo Lugar* Como que lo estaria invocando a la otra clase...

Comment: Volví a leer la pregunta y sigue sin quedarme claro lo que quieres hacer. Sugiero que la leas mientras te pones en los zapatos de quien no tiene idea de lo que estás haciendo, ni de lo que intentas lograr, ni de lo que has intentado hasta ahora o los problemas que tienes y la edites para que esa persona tenga toda la información que necesita para poder ayudarte. Lee [answer] para tomar más ideas de como lograr esto, y quita un momento el pie del acelerador. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que puedes hacer directo la validacion
Este es un ejemplo:

```
public class ejemplo {
String rubro;
public ejemplo(String trabajo){
  this.rubro=trabajo;
}
public boolean isEsencial(){
  if(rubro.equals("Farmaceutico")|rubro.equals("Doctor")){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
public void verificar(){
  if(isEsencial()){
    System.out.println("El trabajo "+rubro+" es esencial");
  }else{
    System.out.println("El trabajo "+rubro+" no es esencial");
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ejemplo e=new ejemplo("Doctor");
    e.verificar();
                
  
  }
}
```

Hasta aqui es lo que pude comprender de tu pregunta..

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende mucho tu duda, pero básicamente si queres comparar Strings debes usar:

```
if(variableString.equalsIgnoreCase("valor contra el cual comparas"))
  //logica por el lado verdadero;
else
 //logica por el lado falso;
```

este metodo retorna true si las cadenas son iguales. Al usar IgnoreCase, es lo mismo si ingresas el nombre con mayúscula o minuscula.

Ahora si lo que buscas comparar son instancias debes usar el metodo instanceof:

```
if(variable instanceof Clase) // se pone el nombre de la clase contra la que comparas
      //logica por el lado verdadero;
    else
     //logica por el lado falso;
```